# Windows doesn't automatically find local devices

Tags: windows, share, smb, nas

I have a local network with a printer, laptop, desktop and a Raspberry Pi that acts as SMB NAS + Kodi + Pi-Hole + a whole lot more.

For a very long time my PC (Win10-latest) would not automatically find some other local network attached devices. The only ones that it would find would be Printer, Router and Kodi (streaming + library).

If I tried mapping a network drive manually or tried to access the local IP of device manually, it would work and then the device would appear under network. *(workaround but still annoying)*

I have tried all the solutions I could find online to enable automatic discovery with no luck:

- Set WiFi to be private
- Enable sharing + discovery
- Make sure workgroup is WORKGROUP
- Manually enable UpNP, SSDP + 2x Function Discovery services
- Check firewall settings and allow File and Printer Sharing (LLMNR-UDP-In) for Domain

Weird thing is, my Android phone with SolidExplored had no problem finding other local devices including the SMB.

Eventually I tried the `net view` command and it came up with:

```
net view
System error 384 has occurred.

You can't connect to the file share because it's not secure. This share requires the obsolete SMB1 protocol, which is unsafe and could expose your system to attack.
```

So I checked `smbstatus` on my Raspberry and it said it is connected with `SMB3_11`. I then manually modified my `smb.conf` file on the Raspberry to be `server min protocol = SMB2` but the *System error 384* continued.

I then enabled `SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support` from `Turn Windows Features on or off` restarted my PC and all my local network devices appear!

I would like to know if anyone else experienced the same issues? I don't even understand what I have misconfigured.

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server min protocol = SMB2
        server role = standalone server
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        guest ok = Yes


[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
        read only = No
        valid users = %S


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        guest ok = No
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes



[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        guest ok = No
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[R]
        comment = 8Tb HD Raspberry Downloads
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
        force group = pi
        force user = pi
        path = /media/pi/Raspberry/Downloads/
        read only = No
        wide links = Yes


[Private]
        comment = 8Tb HD Raspberry Private
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
        force group = pi
        force user = pi
        guest ok = No
        path = /media/pi/Raspberry/Private/
        read only = No
        wide links = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was missing [wsdd](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd). Installed it, setup a systemd service with a few [changes](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/issues/6#issuecomment-470925296) and all works perfect now.